# Transpile a node_module with babel + vuetify + webpack 4

Tags: vue.js, webpack, mocha.js, vuetify.js

I got this error:

```
RUNTIME EXCEPTION  Exception occurred while loading your tests

my-vue-project/node_modules/vuetify/lib/index.js:1

export * from './components';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:872:18)
```

My assumption is that vuetify can't be transpiled into es5. But according to my settings it should. What am I missing?

I'm running my tests with mocha+webpack: with `yarn test`

my `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test nyc --reporter=lcov --reporter=text mochapack --webpack-config webpack.config.js --require test/setup.js test/**/*.spec.js",
    //...
  },
```

my package json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/register": "^7.5.5",
    "@riophae/vue-treeselect": "~0.0.38",
    "@vue/babel-preset-app": "^3.10.0",
    "@vuex-orm/core": "^0.32.1",
    "ajv": "^6.10.0",
    "arraybuffer-to-string": "^1.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "color-convert": "^2.0.0",
    "css-vars-ponyfill": "^2.0.2",
    "e2e": "0.0.8",
    "epic-spinners": "^1.1.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mavon-editor": "^2.7.4",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-forge": "^0.8.3",
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.10.0",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-vue": "^0.8.1",
    "sort-keys": "^3.0.0",
    "string-to-arraybuffer": "^1.0.2",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "v-tooltip": "^2.0.2",
    "vee-validate": "^2.2.12",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.4",
    "vue-form-wizard": "^0.8.4",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.11.2",
    "vue-js-toggle-button": "^1.3.2",
    "vue-lodash": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-moment": "^4.0.0",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-notification": "^1.3.16",
    "vue-picture-input": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-progress": "^0.2.1",
    "vue-range-slider": "^0.6.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.6",
    "vue-search-select": "^2.8.3",
    "vue-select": "^3.1.0",
    "vue-typeahead": "^2.3.2",
    "vue-wait": "^1.3.3",
    "vue-ya-semantic-modal": "~0.0.3",
    "vue2-dropzone": "^3.5.9",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.21.0",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.5.4",
    "vuejs-logger": "^1.5.3",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
    "vuetify": "^2.0.0",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1",
    "vuex-map-fields": "^1.3.4",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^2.5.4",
    "webcrypto-liner": "1.0.1",
    "webcrypto-shim": "^0.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.10.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^3.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "browserstack-local": "^1.4.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chalk": "^2.4.2",
    "chromedriver": "^74.0.0",
    "clone": "^2.1.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "cross-spawn": "^6.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "expect": "^21.2.1",
    "express": "^4.17.0",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sequence": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.7.0",
    "jsdom": "^12.1.0",
    "jsdom-global": "^3.0.2",
    "mocha": "^6.2.0",
    "mochapack": "^1.1.4",
    "mochawesome": "^4.0.1",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "^3.1.5",
    "node-notifier": "^5.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "nyc": "^14.1.1",
    "ora": "^3.4.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.16",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.20",
    "preload-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0-beta.4",
    "qs": "^6.7.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
    "sass": "^1.17.4",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "selenium-server": "^3.141.59",
    "semver": "^6.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.3",
    "sinon": "^7.3.2",
    "sinon-chai": "^3.3.0",
    "sonarqube-scanner": "^2.4.0",
    "uglify-es": "^3.3.10",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.6.3",
    "vue-loader": "^14.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "wdio-browserstack-service": "^0.1.18",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^5.0.1",
    "wdio-iedriver-service": "^0.1.0",
    "wdio-junit-reporter": "^0.4.4",
    "wdio-mocha-framework": "^0.6.4",
    "wdio-mochawesome-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "wdio-sauce-service": "^0.4.14",
    "wdio-selenium-standalone-service": "5.0.0-beta.3",
    "wdio-testrail-custom-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "webdriverajax": "^2.2.0",
    "webdriverio": "^4.14.4",
    "webpack": "^4.39.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 5% in DE",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 10",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 11.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 6.0.0"
  },
  "nyc": {
    "check-coverage": false,
    "per-file": false,
    "instruments": false,
    "lines": 90,
    "statements": 90,
    "functions": 90,
    "branches": 90,
    "include": [
      "apollo-server/**/*.js",
      "src/**/*.{vue,js}"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "apollo-server/*.js",
      "src/*.js"
    ],
    "reporter": [
      "lcov",
      "text",
      "text-summary"
    ],
    "extension": [
      ".js",
      ".vue"
    ],
    "cache": false,
    "all": false
  }
}
```

my `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  externals: [
    require('webpack-node-externals')()
  ],
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            'scss': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ],
            'sass': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
          path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/vuex-loading"),
          // path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/vue-authenticate")
        ],
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          }
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      $t: 'VueI18n',
      $router: 'vue-router'
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    modules: [
      path.resolve('./src'),
      path.resolve('./node_modules')
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map',
};
```

I probably can't exclude that node_module? Even if I did, it would still the same error.